# AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute - Unpickle custom model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle

I have a script called `app.py` which I run in a docker container and which looks like that:

```
from my_ml.flask_blueprints import construct_ml_blueprint
from my_ml.pipeline import PredictPipeline
from flask import Flask, jsonify, Response, request

import re
import json
import os
import operator
from operator import itemgetter
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import joblib
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix, hstack
import pickle

import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_is_fitted, column_or_1d


class LabelEncoderExtension(LabelEncoder):
    def __init__(self, ignore_unknown=False,
                       unknown_original_value='NA',
                       unknown_encoded_value=-1):
        self.ignore_unknown = ignore_unknown
        self.unknown_original_value = unknown_original_value
        self.unknown_encoded_value = unknown_encoded_value

    def transform(self, y):
        check_is_fitted(self, 'classes_')
        y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)

        indices = np.isin(y, self.classes_)
        if not self.ignore_unknown and not np.all(indices):
            raise ValueError("y contains new labels: %s"
                                         % str(np.setdiff1d(y, self.classes_)))

        y_transformed = np.searchsorted(self.classes_, y)
        y_transformed[~indices]=self.unknown_encoded_value
        return y_transformed

    def inverse_transform(self, y):
        check_is_fitted(self, 'classes_')

        labels = np.arange(len(self.classes_))
        indices = np.isin(y, labels)
        if not self.ignore_unknown and not np.all(indices):
            raise ValueError("y contains new labels: %s"
                                         % str(np.setdiff1d(y, self.classes_)))

        y_transformed = np.asarray(self.classes_[y], dtype=object)
        y_transformed[~indices]=self.unknown_original_value
        return y_transformed


# ...
# More code here

def run_app():
    with open('./user-config.json', 'r') as f:
        user_config = json.load(f)
    pipeline = PredictPipeline(user_config=user_config)


    # Load the models
    model_predictor = joblib.load('model.pkl')
    encoders = joblib.load('encoders.pkl')


    @pipeline.step('predict')
    def predict(data, model, params):

    # ...
    # More code here      

    ml_api = construct_ml_blueprint(pipeline)

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.register_blueprint(ml_api)
    print('App loaded')
    return app


def main():
    run_app()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    test = True
    if test:
        test_app = run_app()
        test_app.debug = True
        test_app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
    else:
        main()
else:
    gunicorn_app = run_app()
```

`encoders` is a list of label encoders where each one is made by extending the SkLearn's `LabelEncoder` - my new custom class which inherits `LabelEncoder` is called `LabelEncoderExtension`.

When I run my script I receive the following error:

```
 File "/app.py", line 708, in <module>

    gunicorn_app = run_app()

  File "/app.py", line 569, in run_app

    encoders = joblib.load('encoders.pkl')

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 605, in load

    obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 529, in _unpickle

    obj = unpickler.load()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 1210, in load

    dispatch[key[0]](self)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 1526, in load_global

    klass = self.find_class(module, name)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 1581, in find_class

    return getattr(sys.modules[module], name)

AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'LabelEncoderExtension'
```

How can I fix that?

I found similar posts on the Internet and on StackOverflow and I tested some of the things suggested but still I have not made things work for me.

Two of the most well written of them are the following:

1. https://rebeccabilbro.github.io/module-main-has-no-attribute/
2. https://www.stefaanlippens.net/python-pickling-and-dealing-with-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-thing.html

Comment: Was the model trained on the same (operating) system?

Comment: @Eeshaan, hm not sure exactly about the system but certainly the scripts are different. I trained the model on a script on a server and then I run a Docker container on the same server in a different script with the code above to load the model and do the prediction. To be honest with you, but I may be wrong, the system is probably not related to my problem - check also the links I posted, the issue is much different I think.

Comment: I recently had a problem where model trained on Windows wasn't loading properly on Mac. But then yeah, yours might be something else.

Comment: @Eeshaan ok I see - thank you anyway :)